# How hot does a lithium-ion phone battery have to be before it explodes?

Tags: cellphone, batteries

I have an LG G4, model LG-H810 (serial indicates it's one of the shoddy-soldering ones) and it gets extremely hot during light gaming or while watching videos. It's not too uncommon for me to pick it up by the case and burn myself. I'm concerned that my battery might explode due to the extreme heat. The battery is OAM.
I've seen temperatures of up to 80 celsius (176 farenheit) as reported by both a contact thermometer and CPU-Z. Is this hot enough to cause an explosion?

Comment: Most explosions are not directly caused by temperature issues but indirectly. Usually the issue is a short circuit inside the battery which causes current to flow which causes an increase in temperature causing more current to flow etc. The phone getting hot does not mean that the battery is that hot as well. In a good design it can also mean that the phone gets rid of the heat quite well and so sparing the battery. As long as there are no other events reported of this model's battery exploding, I would not worry too much.

Comment: I would just like to add that while the heat may not pose any immediate risk, it is definitely not helping anything and is reducing the life of the battery faster than it would otherwise.

Comment: Arhennius Law says your battery will have a short life from 60’C rise above 20’C

Comment: Now how do I close questions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three levels for lithium ion cells:

- Max charge temperature
- Max discharge temperature
- Max storage temperature

During charging, the limits are often 40°C or so. (Based on Li-Ion 18650 MF1 cells from LG)

Discharge is higher, 60°C for "standard" cells (such as the MF1s mentioned above), 70°C or 75°C for power tool cells.

Storage temperatures are sometimes the same, sometimes slightly higher than discharge temperatures. I usually work with 70°C as the limit, though some say 80°C.

However none of these temperatures have anything to do with exploding. "Run away thermal event" as they like to call them, usually need temperatures around the 140-160°C depending on which cells you're looking at. However, this is the temperature at the core of the cells, whereas the others are usually rated to the temperature of the external casing of the cell.

As for your particular case, in your phone, I would not worry. The phone will be monitoring the battery and turning off as required, and many handsets have thermal fuses that physically isolate the cell if temperatures get too hot.